# Firebase's RemoteMessage object contains no message ID or sent time

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm testing Firebase's messaging functionality on Android through the API (not Firebase console) but `getMessageId()` returns `null` and `getSentTime()` returns `0`. I can get others fields normally, though. Is this a bug in Firebase or what?

Currently using version 9.2.0 of firebase dependencies.

What I'm sending through the API is:

```
{
    "to":"frL...",
    "data":{"title":"Hi",
            "body":"such body"
    }
}
```

I'm sending `notification` fields in the `data` field because I want to handle the notification manually, which I cannot do if I use the `notification` field.

Comment: how are you getting the other fields. Kindly share what types of data you are sending from the server ?

Comment: what version of the SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug fixed in version 9.4. More info here https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#9.4

> RemoteMessage#getMessageId() now returns the correct message-id for received messages. Previously, it returned null.

Comment: Please quote the relevant text.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Done ;)

Comment: its fixed for getMessageId() but what how to get sentTime() IOS please???